# How To Use Function Variables With Another Function

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating web site. In this web site, I have created a Registration Form. User can Input details and when user clicks Submit button all the data save into the database. Here is my saveInvoice function. In my view page I have used saveInvoice  as my action. Then I used request inputs in this function.

```
public function saveInvoice(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::user())
        {
            $settings = Setting::find(1);
            $invoiceNo=$settings->invoiceprefix.''.str_pad($settings->invoiceno, $settings->invoicepadding, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

            $invoice= new Invoice();
            $invoice->invoicereference=$invoiceNo;
            $invoice->firstname=$request->fname;
            $invoice->lastname=$request->lname;

            $invoice->save();

            $settings->invoiceno=$settings->invoiceno+1;
            $settings->update();

            if($invoice == null){
                return redirect()->back()->with('msg','invalid request');
            }
            else{
                return redirect()->route('invoice.preview',$invoiceNo);
            }
        }

    }
```

But , Now I want to create another function called sendemail. In this function I want to use user inputs which user has filled in that registration form. Can I get those request inputs from this above function or is there a another method ??

```
public function sendemail(Request $request) {
$invoiceNo = $request->input('invoiceNo');
            $fname = $request->input('fname');
            $Qty = $request->input('Qty');
            $price = $request->input('price');
            $sendemail = $request->input('email');

            $data = [];
            $data['invoiceNo'] = $invoiceNo;
            $data['fname'] = $fname;
            $data['Qty'] = $Qty;
            $data['price'] = $price;
            $data['sendemail'] = $sendemail;

            Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->to($data["sendemail"], 'TicketBooker')->subject
                ('CheapEfares Air Ticket');
                $message->from('kistlakall@gmail.com', 'CheapEfares');
            });
}
```

Comment: do you have sperate URL/route for senmail function ?

Comment: I imagine you can pass a `Request` object to your `sendemail` function.  Do you try to do that?  Where do you call that function?

Comment: @DsRaj - I have a separate route for sendmail function.

Comment: @David - But, How can I Request objects to my sendmail function ??

Comment: It means you want to redirect with the request ?

Comment: @DsRaj - I want to Send a email by using users inputs. Thats why I request objects.. How can I do this ??

Comment: If the function is in the same controller then: $this->sendemail($request); call like this

Comment: @DsRaj - Yh , It Worked !! :D

Comment: @Amithash I have added the answer with the description for other users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call sendemail function within saveInvoice function and then pass the Request object to sendemail function like

```
public function saveInvoice(Request $request){
//save invoice code

if($invoice == null){
  return redirect()->back()->with('msg','invalid request');
}
else{
  $this->sendemail(Request $request);
  return redirect()->route('invoice.preview',$invoiceNo);
}
}
```

I am assuming both the functions are in same class or one class is extending other class

Comment: I used without Request like this - $this->sendemail($request); This worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call that method from your code
and on the return of that method, you can set up your response.

```
$this->sendemail($request); // $this just because it is on same controller or basecontroller

// For example
public function saveInvoice(Request $request){
    .
    .
    .
    $sendMail = $this->sendemail($request);
    if($sendMail == 'success'){
        // On success
    } else {
        // On Error 
    }
} 
public function sendemail(Request $request) {
    .
    .
    .
    return 'success';
}
```

Comment: No , Now I can't even send the email. When I try this, it gives me this , Type error: Too few arguments to function.

Comment: You need to set a default value for your extra parameter as in your updated question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50809510/5503275 you need as $total = null

Comment: Yh , When I used null it worked.. But , Now I get this error - Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. ??

Comment: Okay , I Will check.. Thank U !!